# How to generate a set of co-ordinates for a circle in python using the circle formula?

Tags: python, geometry

Looking to generate a set of whole integer co-ordinates for a circle using a user specified point, working with the formula for a circle: (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2

How can i do this in a 3d space, finding the co-ordinates of x,y and z.

Comment: Do you want integer coordinates only points on a circle?    Is the radius also an integer?  What is "user specified point" - center?, radius?, a point on the circle?

Comment: user specified point is the centre, the radius will always be fixed at either 2 or 3, and yes only integers for the co ordinates

Comment: then only the four points (a +/- r, b), (a, b +/- r) will be integers for integer a, b.  To make it more interesting you need bigger radii chosen from Pythagorean Triples

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense in 3D if you give the equation of a circle lying in the xy plane (obviously such that z=0). when you say integer coordinates, are you after a digital circle ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Parametrics

Don't use the Cartesian format of the equations, use the [parametric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation) one

Instead of having (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2, you have

x = r * cos(t) + a

y = r * sin(t) + b

t, or more commonly for trigonometric functions, θ, is an angle between 0 and 2π

### **Example code**

```
import math

a = 2
b = 3
r = 3

#The lower this value the higher quality the circle is with more points generated
stepSize = 0.1

#Generated vertices
positions = []

t = 0
while t < 2 * math.pi:
    positions.append((r * math.cos(t) + a, r * math.sin(t) + b))
    t += stepSize

print(positions)
```

### Spheres

As this is a 2-dimensional surface, a second parameter will be required as one is insufficient

u = [0, 2π]
v = [-π/2, π/2]

x = r * sin(u) * cos(v) + a

y = r * cos(u) * cos(v) + b

z = r * sin(v) + c

```
import math

a = 2
b = 3
c = 7
r = 3

#The lower this value the higher quality the circle is with more points generated
stepSize = 0.1

#Generated vertices
positions = []

u = 0
v = -math.pi/2
while u < 2 * math.pi:
    while v < math.pi/2:
        positions.append((r * math.sin(u) * math.cos(v) + a, r * math.cos(u) * math.cos(v) + b, r * math.sin(v) +  c))
        v += stepSize
    u += stepSize

print(positions)
```

Comment: how can i do this but with a 3d space with where the circle would have co-ordinates x,y and z

Comment: I have added this to the answer

Comment: @RobJackson: How does this answer the question in 3D ? A sphere is not a circle.

Comment: My bad, I misread his request as one for a sphere and not a circle in 3d space

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question but no one has suggested using any kind of reflection.

Using the code from the accepted answer as a template.

```
import math 

# center of the circle
center_x = 50
center_y = 50
# radius of the circle
r = 99

# automatic calculation of the step size to get all of the 
# integer x, y coords around the circle
factor = int(r / 10)

if factor == 0:
    factor = 1
else:
    factor *= 100

step_size = 0.01 / factor

#Generated vertices
quad = set()
count = 0
half_pi = math.pi / 2

while count < half_pi:
    quad.add((int(round(r * math.cos(count))), int(round(r * math.sin(count)))))
    count += step_size 

coords = (
    list((x + center_x, y + center_y) for x, y in quad) + 
    list((-x + center_x, y + center_y) for x, y in quad) + 
    list((-x + center_x, -y + center_y) for x, y in quad) + 
    list((x + center_x, -y + center_y) for x, y in quad)
)

print(coords)
```

In the above code I am calculating the integer x, y coords and putting them into a set so there are no duplicates. If a whole circle is being calculated then only a single quadrant needs to be done and then we can reflect those coords to the remaining 3 quadrants and that will give you a full circle.

This code is 4.2 times faster as calculated using the Python timeit module being run 10000 times.